# M1 Mac OSx Bigsur: have to re-install Command Line Tools after every system update

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur, xcode-command-line-tools

On my new macbook pro M1 with Bigsur I have to re-install Command Line Tools every time I have installed a system update. When Launching the terminal and running `brew doctor` home-brew complains that neither git nor Command Line Tools are installed:

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Git could not be found in your PATH.
Homebrew uses Git for several internal functions, and some formulae use Git
checkouts instead of stable tarballs. You may want to install Git:
  brew install git

Warning: No developer tools installed.
Install the Command Line Tools:
  xcode-select --install
```

Once I have run: `xcode-select --install` (and yes it does really install Command Line Tools again because it takes about 5 minutes) everything works again until next time an OSx update comes around the computer reboots. Why could this be happening? I never had those issues before?

Comment: I have always had to re-run `xcode-select` after a system update.  Each update usually requires a new SDK.  Not sure about the `git` thing, though.

Comment: Hmm that's interesting. I don't recall having to go through that on my previous intel macbook pro 

Comment: It's Big Sur, not the M1. I have an Intel MBP on Big Sur, and it does the same thing. I still have Mojave on my iMac, and this doesn't happen on it.

Comment: This exact thing has been happening to me too. It's infuriating! I have a new Macbook Air M1 with Big Sur.